# How to resolve Dynamics CRM Plugin System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission error

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

**Business Process Error**
**System.Security.SecurityException:** Request for the permission of type '**System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission**, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes, Boolean checkHost)
at RetrieveAttachments.RetrieveClass.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
MyComputer

I also added following method in plugin AssemblyInfo.cs file
 **[assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]**
but its raise same error.

```
QueryExpression notes = new QueryExpression { EntityName = "annotation", ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("filename", "subject", "annotationid", "documentbody","mimetype") };
notes.Criteria.AddCondition("annotationid", ConditionOperator.Equal, annotationid);
     EntityCollection NotesRetrieve = service.RetrieveMultiple(notes);
     if (NotesRetrieve != null && NotesRetrieve.Entities.Count > 0)
     {
      foreach (var note in NotesRetrieve.Entities)
      {
       string fileName = note.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename");
       string cleanFileName = string.Empty;
       foreach (var chr in fileName.ToCharArray().ToList())
       {
        if(!Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Contains(chr)) cleanFileName = cleanFileName + chr; 
       }
     FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, @"D:\note");
     string fileLocation = Path.Combine(@"D:\note", cleanFileName);
     byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(NotesRetrieve.Entities[0].Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());
     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation, fileContent);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Reading file from a sandbox plugin is prohibited. Try to change isolation mode to none.

Comment: Hi @Marat changing isolation mode in Plugin registration tool is not possible and Dynamics CRM supports Sandbox mode

Comment: What version are you using? Is it online? If it isn't online it should be possible to change isolation mode to none.

Comment: Changing the isolation mode is possible if you are using CRM on-premise and you are a deployment administrator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/gg309580.aspx.

Comment: You are right, you have to be deployment admin to register plugin in isolation mode.

Comment: so it is not possible to register a plugin in none isolation mode

Comment: What exactly are you douing in your code? Are you reading a file? As I know such error occures in several cases. Could you share you code?

Comment: I guess you understand that with CRM Online, the code runs on a Microsoft server. The file url indicated in the code does not make sense in that context.

Comment: Your code is trying to access D drive of the server in Data Center which is prohibited. You have to find any other solution to implement your buiness logic

Comment: Hi @Nicolas Basically i have a requirement to download all attachment file from Note Entity using plug-In button and save them in my local machine D:\ drive

Comment: Hi @MaratDeykun Basically i have a requirement to download all attachment file from Note Entity using plug-In button and save them in my local machine D:\ drive ...could you suggest me other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your plugin is registered in sandbox then this could be the problem. Try to register it outside of the sandbox. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752(v=crm.6).aspx) you can find information about trust levels

Comment: Hi @pen i saw the link which you had given it gives following solution by changing this registry key value, you can change the web access for sandbox plug-ins but its done only by System Administrator. How i register a plugin outside of the sandbox just because Dynamics CRM supports Sandbox mode.

Comment: Hi, as you can read in link that I posted "For a Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online deployment, plug-ins or custom workflow activities must be registered in the sandbox". Can you edit your post and share code that is throwing an exception?

Comment: Developers have the option of registering their plug-ins in the sandbox, known as partial trust, or outside the sandbox, known as full trust. Full trust is supported for on-premises and Internet-facing Microsoft Dynamics CRM deployments. For a Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online deployment, plug-ins or custom workflow activities must be registered in the sandbox (partial trust) where they are isolated as previously described.

Comment: I also added the code in question which throws the exception.

Comment: You can do that only when you have CRM On-permise. It can't be done on CRM Online.