# Getting Plug-In Path error while Downloading attachments from Note entity and saving into local machine in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#-4.0, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Business Process Error

> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. at
>   System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path) at
>   System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes,
>   Boolean checkHost)at
>   RetrieveAttachments.RetrieveClass.Execute(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)

The code is as follows:

```
QueryExpression notes = new QueryExpression { EntityName = "annotation", ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("filename", "subject", "annotationid", "documentbody","mimetype") };
                    notes.Criteria.AddCondition("annotationid", ConditionOperator.Equal, annotationid);
                    EntityCollection NotesRetrieve = service.RetrieveMultiple(notes);
                    if (NotesRetrieve != null && NotesRetrieve.Entities.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var note in NotesRetrieve.Entities)
                        {
                        string fileName = note.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename");
                        //string fileType = note.GetAttributeValue<string>("mimetype");
                        FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, "D:\\note");
                        string fileLocation = f+ fileName;
                        byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(NotesRetrieve.Entities[0].Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation, fileContent); 
                        }

                     }
                   }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.ToString());
                   }
```

Comment: Whats the file name? Also where is D:\note, on the server?

Comment: No D:\note is a path of my machine where the file is downloaded, and fileName is the name of file which is attached as a attachment file in a Note entity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Santosh,

You can use following code to download attachments from Note entity in Dynamics CRM online.

code for .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int choice;
            CrmServiceClient crmConn = new CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM"].ConnectionString);
            IOrganizationService crmService = crmConn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
                    QueryExpression w_query = new QueryExpression { EntityName = "annotation", ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("filename","documentbody") };

                    EntityCollection w_account = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(w_query);
                     string name = "";
                    foreach (var count in w_account.Entities)
                    {
                        name = count.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename");

                        string doc_content = count.GetAttributeValue<string>("documentbody");
                        System.IO.FileStream wFile;
                        byte[] byteData = null;
                        if (name != null)
                        {
                            byte[] doc = Convert.FromBase64String(count.GetAttributeValue<string>("documentbody"));
                            byteData = doc;
                            wFile = new FileStream("D:\\attachments\\" + name, FileMode.Append);
                            wFile.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
                            wFile.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Please find all attachments in your local D: drive");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                    Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }

    }
```

Code for .config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRM" connectionString="AuthType=Office365;Url=https://your_organization_url; Username=your_user_name; Password=Your_password" />
  </connectionStrings>


    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.22.0.0" newVersion="2.22.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.22.0.0" newVersion="2.22.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You just need to edit .config file code, this should work for you.

Note:you have to create C# console application and add required assemblies from Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

> D:\note is a path of my machine where the file is downloaded.

If the above means you are trying to use a CRM plugin to write data to your local machine - as opposed to the CRM server - then this will never work.

The plugin runs on the CRM server so it wont have access to your client machine. E.g. when the plugin runs its looking for `D:\note` on the CRM server - not on your personal computer.

If you want to download files to your local machine you are better of creating a console application that runs on your local machine.

In any case there is an example of attachment downloading [here](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/exporting-annotation-note-attachment/). `filePath` in your case would be `D:\note` (this still won't work in a plugin though).

```
public void ExportDocuments(IOrganizationService service, String filePath)
{
     String fetch = @"<fetch mapping='logical' count='100' version='1.0'>
          <entity name='annotation'>
               <attribute name='filename' />
               <attribute name='documentbody' />
               <attribute name='mimetype' />
          </entity>
     </fetch>";

     foreach (Entity e in service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch)))
     {
          if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString()))
          {
               byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(e.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());

               File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + e.Attributes["filename"].ToString(), data);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: HI @James thanks for your response...could you elaborate me your code  `public void ExportDocuments(IOrganizationService service, String filePath)` what is **filePath** here

Comment: and by using fetch query is it possible to download 20k attachment records?

Comment: `filePath` is just wherever you want to download the documents, e.g. `D;\note`. For 20k records you will need to page the results https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327917.aspx

Comment: HI @James so it's possible to download all attachment files from Note entity to my computer local drive D:\note folder by using your logic? you also suggest that creating a console application that runs on your local machine..could you elaborate how is it possible?

Comment: should the ExportDocuments method is called after Execute method? could you give me complete code?

Answer (score 0):

This line is part of you culprit:

`string fileLocation = f+ fileName;`

This line is going to create an invalid file name because `FileIOPermission.ToString()` returns an XML fragment.

Here is an example to fix that issue, clean the filename of illegal characters, and use `Path.Combine` to build a valid file path.

```
string fileName = note.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename");
string cleanFileName = string.Empty;

    foreach (var chr in fileName.ToCharArray().ToList())
    {
        if (!Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Contains(chr)) cleanFileName = cleanFileName + chr; 
    }

FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, @"D:\note");
string fileLocation = Path.Combine(@"D:\note", cleanFileName);
byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(NotesRetrieve.Entities[0].Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation, fileContent);
```

Comment: Hi @Nicknow sir, thanks for your reply, i used this code but it gave same error :"Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."

Comment: actually the object "f" of FileIOPermission created a permission of write a file but i think it is not to be granted to the required path....

Comment: I got this error "Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed." while i have not used the FileIOPermission but when i used it, i did not get any error.

Comment: thats not the same error. Your question had an error related to invalid characters in the file name and my answer resolved that problem. What you are describing is a NEW issue and should be posted as a NEW question.

Comment: Hi @Nicknow sir, i have posted the new question here open following URL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347386/how-to-resolve-dynamics-crm-plugin-system-security-permissions-fileiopermission

Answer (score 0):

CRM Online supports only Sandbox mode that means it isolates the code, You can't access outside environment in Sandbox mode which in your case is you local computer drive.

To achieve your goal you can create a console application as [James Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569689/james-wood/) have said, that will write files into your local machine.

Comment: Okay @Kunal thanks for your response..hope you will help me to achieve my goal