# Getting System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission error while working with Plug-In in Online Dynamics CRM 2016

Tags: .net, security, plugins, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

> Business Process Error System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes, Boolean checkHost) at RetrieveAttachments.RetrieveClass.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) The action that failed was: Demand The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer

Plug-In code is followed:

```
        try
          {

            QueryExpression notes = new QueryExpression { EntityName = "annotation", ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("filename", "subject", "annotationid", "documentbody","mimetype") };
            notes.Criteria.AddCondition("annotationid", ConditionOperator.Equal, annotationid);
            EntityCollection NotesRetrieve = service.RetrieveMultiple(notes);
            if (NotesRetrieve != null && NotesRetrieve.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var note in NotesRetrieve.Entities)
                {
                       string fileName =note.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename");
                       string cleanFileName = string.Empty;
                       foreach (var chr in fileName.ToCharArray().ToList())
                       {
                           if (!Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Contains(chr)) cleanFileName = cleanFileName + chr;
                       }
                       FileIOPermission writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, @"D:\note");      
                       writePermission.Demand();
                       string filePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\note", cleanFileName);
                       byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(NotesRetrieve.Entities[0].Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());
                       System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileContent);


                 }

             }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.ToString());
           }
```

Comment: As you already learned in your two other questions about this, you cannot save files to the server's local drive in a sandboxed plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347386/how-to-resolve-dynamics-crm-plugin-system-security-permissions-fileiopermission

Comment: yeah i have already post the same problem in my previous questions but i cannot found a better approach to solve it? so if you have any solution than suggest me?

Comment: What exactly do you imagine your code does? Where is it your expectation that the files you save end up?

Comment: and in my previous question i have not mentioned that whether it's online or on-premise? so i cannot get proper solution.

Comment: i have also debug my code it works properly at filename its retrieve file name and at filepath it combined path also fileContent retrieved but when the File.WriteAllBytes created file its throws me to catch

Answer (score 3):

I have bad news for you. When you develop plugins for CRM Online it will not have an access to server resources (like file system in your case) so your code will never work in CRM Online environment.

Comment: alas, so sad..hahaha

Comment: so could you suggest me another approach to resolve it?

Comment: Can you please provide your scenario because I understand what your code does but I don't know your final goal.

Comment: okay @Andrii basically i want to create a Plug-in button which download all attachment file from Note Entity

Comment: the code which i post in my question its only for single note entity attachment file

Comment: Download and put where?

Comment: in my local storage drive

Comment: Then plugin is not your case because plugin can interact with CRM endpoint and external endpoints - check this article -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx. To download files to your local storage drive you will have to develop Console application but not a plugin.

Comment: okay @Andrii thanks for your response...james wood also suggest me the solution that its not possible with plugin [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39367657/getting-plug-in-path-error-while-downloading-note-attachment-file-and-save-into).

Comment: so could you elaborate me how i develop the Console application?

Comment: @SantoshRawat, did you google for it? first result -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695803(v=crm.7).aspx